# Shuffling a table using Javascript or PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, html-table

I am new to Javascript and PHP and I am practicing to build a quiz where the choices are randomized. I'm just wondering if you can shuffle or randomize all that is inside a row of a table?
Is it Possible to randomize This each line all together?

```
1.<tr><td > <input type="radio" name="answer" value="optiona">a</input> </td></tr>
2.<tr><td > <input type="radio" name="answer" value="optionb">b</input> </td></tr>
3.<tr><td > <input type="radio" name="answer" value="optionc">c</input> </td></tr>
4.<tr><td > <input type="radio" name="answer" value="optiond">d</input> </td></tr>
```

My question is.. is it possible to randomize the 4 rows in PHP or JavaScript everytime I refresh the page or someone takes the quiz?

Comment: It is easier to shuffle an array the table is generated from, then generate the array in that new order.

Comment: Is there a way in doing in that form?

Comment: If your problem has been solved, don't forget to accept an answer.

Answer (score 2):

It would be easiest to do this in PHP.

Simply do `shuffle($array);`

[Documentation for `shuffle()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php)

Comment: Like This Sir?

<?php
$my_array = array("1.<tr><td > <input type="radio" name="answer" value="optiona">a</input> </td></tr>",
"2.<tr><td > <input type="radio" name="answer" value="optionb">b</input> </td></tr>",
"3.<tr><td > <input type="radio" name="answer" value="optionc">c</input> </td></tr>",
"4.<tr><td > <input type="radio" name="answer" value="optiond">d</input> </td></tr>");

shuffle($my_array);
print_r($my_array);
?>

Comment: @LouisseMinelleGalangII Yes, perfect. However, I would recommend getting rid of the `1.`, `2.`, etc from each of the possible answers. Also, if you need to share code in comments, I would recommend using [this website](http://pastebin.com/)

Comment: Hello sir what if... If I will insert <?php ?> inside the row <tr><td> <?php ?> like this </td> <tr> isnt it prohibited to insert PHP inside a PHP? get my point?

Comment: @LouisseMinelleGalangII do you mean <?php ?> inside .PHP or <?php ?> inside <?php ?>

Comment: @LouisseMinelleGalangII If you mean the latter one, you can do something like `$a = "<tr><td> $b like this </td></tr>";` since you are using `"` brackets, you can include variables inside. Same principle, you can't type dollar signs in `""`s unless you escape it as `"\$"` to display `$`.

Answer (score 1):

Seeing the comment under Mister Dood's answer, I should warn that stuffing HTML in an array is suboptimal, as you lose the ability to manipulate it easily. Try this:

```
$array = array(
  "a" => "Answer A",
  "b" => "Answer B",
  "c" => "Answer C",
  "d" => "Answer D"
);

shuffle($array);

$count = 0;
foreach ($array as $value => $text) {
  ?><tr><td><?php
    echo ++$count;
  ?></td><td><label for="answer<?php
    echo $value;
  ?>"><input type="radio" name="answer" id="answer<?php
    echo $value;
  ?>" value="<?php
    echo $value;
  ?>"><?php
    echo $text;
  ?></label></td></tr><?php
}
```